# Class vs Module in designing Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, api, design-patterns, inheritance, composition

When I read more about Ruby metaprogramming, most of the time we found at least two solutions to solve a problem. Please look at two examples below:

```
class Base
  def self.has_many(*args)
    # ...
  end
end

class Student < Base
  has_many :books
end
```

Another style:

```
module Base
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_many(*args)
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class Student
  include Base

  has_many :books
end
```

But when we design api, we have to decide which one to use, but I would like to ask your ideas and some of best practices that most people have already implemented in their libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your API is providing the base functionality which will be extended by the client, then you should prefer **inheritance**.

If your API is going to extend various clients with their own base functionality, then you should go for **composition**.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of theories around that question.

I tend to prefer composition because it makes behavior a lot more reusable that way but if you look at Rails, you'll have to subclass ActiveRecord::Base class every time you want to an object in your database. If you look at DataMapper, it's the opposite as they just required you to include DataMapper::Resource.

Inheritance vs Composition (via modules) is a big topic and the question you'll have to ask yourself will come down to: how can I achieve the greater decoupling between the components I provide and another user existing code base?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby supports single inheritance only. Therefore if API client must inherit your base class, they lose the ability to inherit other classes. Using module inclusion you make possible a code like:

```
class Student < Person
  include Base
  has_many :books
end
```

And thus you can "inherit" both Person and Base.

However, classical inheritance syntax looks more natural and less "magic"